# Prevent "mv" command from raising error if no file matches the glob. eg" mv *.json /dir/

Tags: bash, shell, mv

I want to move all JSON files created within a jenkins job to a different folder.

It is possible that the job does not create any json file.
In that case the mv command is raising an error and so that job is failing.

How do I prevent mv command from raising error in case no file is found?

Comment: Probably you can not "prevent" mv(1) from raising error. You can redirect its *standard error* in order to not see errors, or - better - you can check before calling mv.

Comment: If no file matches the glob, `mv` "sees" the literal `*.json` as source file, and that of course doesn't exist... the only thing you could do is redirecting the output so you don't *see* the error, but it happens, so it's there.

Comment: ... and if you set `shopt -s nullglob` in `mv *.json target` target becomes the source.

Comment: What have you tried? This might even be an upvote question (it's a good one) if you'd shown your attempts and included an MCVE. See [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: within a *for* loop use *[ -e "$file" ] || continue*

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 2):

Loop over all json files and move each of them, if it exists, in a oneliner:

```
for X in *.json; do [[ -e $X ]] && mv "$X" /dir/; done
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior -- it's *why* the shell leaves `*.json` unexpanded when there are no matches, to allow `mv` to show a useful error.

If you don't want that, though, you can always check the list of files yourself, before passing it to `mv`. As an approach that works with all POSIX-compliant shells, not just bash:

```
#!/bin/sh

# using a function here gives us our own private argument list.
# that's useful because minimal POSIX sh doesn't provide arrays.
move_if_any() {
  dest=$1; shift  # shift makes the old $2 be $1, the old $3 be $2, etc.
  # so, we then check how many arguments were left after the shift;
  # if it's only one, we need to also check whether it refers to a filesystem
  # object that actually exists.
  if [ "$#" -gt 1 ] || [ -e "$1" ] || [ -L "$1" ]; then
    mv -- "$@" "$dest"
  fi
}

# put destination_directory/ in $1 where it'll be shifted off
# $2 will be either nonexistent (if we were really running in bash with nullglob set)
# ...or the name of a legitimate file or symlink, or the string '*.json'
move_if_any destination_directory/ *.json
```

...or, as a more bash-specific approach:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=( *.json )
if (( ${#files[@]} > 1 )) || [[ -e ${files[0]} || -L ${files[0]} ]]; then
  mv -- "${files[@]}" destination/
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

Why do you not want the error?

If you just don't want to *see* the error, then you could always just throw it away with `2>/dev/null`, but PLEASE don't do that. Not every error is the one you expect, and this is a debugging *nightmare*. You could write it to a log with `2>$logpath` and then build in logic to read that to make certain it's ok, and ignore or respond accordingly --

```
mv *.json /dir/ 2>$someLog
executeMyLogParsingFunction # verify expected err is the ONLY err
```

If it's because you have `set -e` or a `trap` in place, and you *know* it's ok for the `mv` to fail (which might not be because there is no file!), then you can use this trick -

```
mv *.json /dir/ || echo "(Error ok if no files found)"
```

or

```
mv *.json /dir/ ||: # : is a no-op synonym for "true" that returns 0
```

see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html

(If it's failing simply because the `mv` is returning a nonzero as the last command, you could also add an explicit `exit 0`, but don't do that either - fix the actual problem rather than patching the symptom. Any of these other solutions should handle that, but I wanted to point out that unless there's a `set -e` or a `trap` that catches the error, it shouldn't cause the script to fail unless it's the very last command.)

Better would be to specifically handle the problem you *expect* without disabling error handling on other problems.

```
shopt -s nullglob # globs with no match do not eval to the glob as a string
for f in *.json; do mv "$f" /dir/; done # no match means no loop entry
```

c.f. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html
or if you don't want to use `shopt`,

```
for f in *.json; do [[ -e "$f" ]] && mv "$f" /dir/; done
```

Note that I'm only testing existence, so that will include any match, including directories, symlinks, named pipes... you might want `[[ -f "$f" ]] && mv "$f" /dir/` instead.

c.f. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html